# Angular RXJS ShareReplay()

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
post(endpoint: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
        const browser_id = this.utl.getBrowserId;
        data = { ...data, browser_id };
        const url = this.apiUrl + endpoint;
        const header = this.getHeader();
        const rq = this.http.post(url, data, header)
            .pipe(catchError((error) => {
                this.checkPossibleAuthError(error);
                return of(error);
            }), shareReplay(1))

        return rq;
    }
```

everytime i call on this post request it creates new request

i was expecting it to return previous response with same endpoint and payload

Comment: You would need to return the same `rq` instance every time and then every call would return the same data after the first execution. You are creating a new instance with every call in your code. As you are passing in end point and data which might be different you would need some way to track the instances as well based on the incoming parameters.

Comment: alright thanks, i will look into this, been thinking shareplay() wont be a perfect solution here since i'm having dynamic endpoint and payloads being passed to this func

Comment: you could create a `Map()` where you store the payload as a key, and the response as a value. This way you create a sort of cache